# How to gracefully shut down monogodb 0.8 running in docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, shutdown

I am starting mongodb via the ENTRYPOINT config in a docker file.
It works fine. However, when I execute:

```
docker stop <containerid>
```

it seems to be sending a SIGTERM to the process. Which means the `mongod.lock` file is not cleared. How can I gracefully shutdown a running docker container so that the right signals are sent to the process running inside docker ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am not sure to understand. `docker stop <id>` will indeed send a SIGTERM. This is by design. If the process didn't shutdown properly within the timeout (default is 10 sec), then a SIGKILL is emitted.

At the moment, we do have some issue with the signal propagation though. It is due to the pid namespace and the fact that the process has a pid 1. This should get fixed soon with the new execution plugins.

Comment: I actually want the ability to stop a container but instead of sending SIGTERM, I want to send SIGINT. Is this possible in docker 0.8 ?

Comment: I think I have found a solution. I need to manage the process using supervisord.

Comment: you can do `docker kill -s INT <id>`

Comment: @creack, What I cannot understand is when using docker stop, to which process will SIGTREM be sent? lets say I am using an entrypoint.sh script which starts 3 services. To whom will kill sign be sent? if only to the entrypoint, then the other services will die unproperly (that is exactly what I am getting with apache or samba winbindd).

Comment: The signal is sent to the entrypoint. The kernel will propagate the signal to the group ID, so unless the children orphan themself, They will get the signal. Apache & other might orphan themself though, in which case, your entrypoint should handle it (maybe "trap pkill" or something) However, I recommend using a single process per container which makes everything simpler, safer and easier to reproduce.

Comment: @creack, I was yesterday doing some experiments about that, I always run bash session at the end of my script to block the entrypoint from exiting in a way that make sense (I don't like tail, bash makes more sense for me), but when using bash, my entrypoint cannot handle any SIGNAL, could you help me in that? I created a quesion about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41709975/my-bash-script-doesnt-respond-to-signals-when-opening-new-shell-session?

Killling each bash process manually for each container before closing them is not a practical solution as well.

Comment: "This should get fixed soon" which version fixed this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using docker 0.9. SIGTERM will be sent to process with PID=1 inside a container when call *docker stop* . So we can manage sub-processes with supervisord, runit.

The problem is when we call *$ service docker stop|restart*, or the host machine reset. Docker will not send SIGTERM to all running containers. I'm trying to solve this case.

Answer (score 1):

Using Docker 0.9 or later, it will send SigTerm to the 1st process (which is running inside container) by default.

But notice the environment variable file (/etc/default/docker in Ubuntu and /etc/sysconfig/docker in CentOS) should include **DOCKER_OPTS=" -r=false "** (or **other_args=" -r=false"** in CentOS) for stopping docker from autorestart container.

For example, I'm using this configuration: 
**DOCKER_OPTS=" -g /mydir/docker -r=false --dns 8.8.4.4 "**

If you want to run multi-process inside one container, you should using **supervisord** as the 1st process, supervisord will manage other processes and transfer signals to them.