# My Bash script doesn't respond to SIGNALS when opening new shell session

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, sh

I have this simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap "rm /testfile; service apache2 stop;" SIGTERM
service apache2 start
# Here I want to create new bash session for some reasons.
/bin/bash
```

Now some another program can somewhen send `SIGTERM` to this script, but **actually the script does NOT respond to that signal, it keeps hanging in the new bash session**, the same case when I use something else like `sleep infinity` instead of opening new bash session (that was just for testing because I need that bash session).

**How can I make this script response to that SIGTERM?** It doesn't matter how the new bash session will be terminated, I just want to make sure that what I write in `trap` will be executed.

Comment: As @Fred says. You are essentially, executing `service apache2 start` before `trap "rm /testfile; service apache2 stop;" SIGTERM` is ever called. You would want to include the `start` in the `trap`. Probably best to have `trap` call a helper script that does both the `stop` (`rm`) and `start`. (your second `/bin/bash` isn't helping)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Why would the other process not simply stop Apache instead of signalling this script in order to make this script stop Apache?

Comment: check this out - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146756/forward-sigterm-to-child-in-bash

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, what do you mean that I am calling the trap before my service apache2 start heppns? That is exactly the purpose of traps, handling some unexpeted data or situationon. So in my case I just defined my trap, and then contiued executing my code, what is wring in that?

Comment: @IndraUprade actually that helps partially, the idea is practice if you want just to block your code some how ,but that doesn't work with /bin/bash unfortuanatelly.

Comment: @Fred, if you know Docker, I am starting Docker container, which starts some services, and then I prefer to start bash session, instead of blocking my entrypoint some how (e.g. tail), so bash makes more sense, but in that case, the docker container will not be able to quit gracefully when issuing docker stop command, and my services will be killed, not gracefully closed.

Comment: Your script will not execute the `trap` until it is *terminated*. You start apache before the `trap` is executed on term which then kills apache. None of that matters if you spawn a new sub-process `/bin/bash` because your original script never completes and killing the parent kills the child.

Answer (score 1):

The trap is not called until the shell in which it is defined gets control back.  Since you launch bash and this new process takes control, the trap never gets called.

Comment: Can`t I some how make my shell script kill the sub-bash session when he receives some signal?

Comment: If the "sub-bash" is to the foreground, I do not think you can.  But your script is not trying to do that, it is trying to kill Apache.  If you want to kill the "sub-bash", why do not you signal its process instead of trying to signal the parent?  For reference, if a process has children in the background, it will receive signals after the next command it is executing terminates (including if it is blocked by a "wait" statement waiting on some other process to finish) and then can kill the children.  If I understood what you are trying to achieve, maybe I could suggest something.

Comment: If you know Docker, I am starting Docker container, which starts some services, and then I prefer to start bash session, instead of blocking my entrypoint some how (e.g. tail), so bash makes more sense, but in that case, the docker container will not be able to quit gracefully when issuing docker stop command, and my services will be killed, not gracefully closed. So I have to send SIGTERM to the parent bash, because I am using docker stop, which deals only with the parent bash. if that is not possible, so I will just forget that and not start my Docker container with Bash :), thank you!

Comment: Could you do the opposite : create child process in the background that starts Apache and traps signals (and can be signaled to terminate Apache)?  If that works, I could suggest simple changes to your code to achieve that.

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what you mean